# What is the intuitive notion that ZF minus Extensionality minus Regularity plus Collection capture?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

In order to clarify my questions I'll here introduce the concept of ***intuitive completeness*** of an axiomatic system, an axiomatic set A of a consistent theory would be said to be *intuitively complete* if for some intuitive notion I all very basic aspects of I are grasped by  A . For example  ZFC seem's to be complete with respect to the intuitive notion "Set", basically because it contains the axioms of Extensionality and (to some authors) Foundation. Had it missed these axioms, then it would have been deemed intuitively incomplete with respect to the intuitive notion of 'set'.

Now it is known that the following axiomatic system, a fragment of the axiomatic system of  ZFC, is equi-interpretable with the whole of  ZFC:

1. Set Union
2. Power
3. Separation
4. Collection
5. Infinity

Definitely this system is not intuitively complete with respect to intuitive notion 'set'.

This fragment is technically interesting, simply because most of mathematics can be interpreted in it, hence this question about its intuitive completeness.

**Question:** is there a known intuitive notion I that the above axiomatic system is intuitively complete with respect to it?

Dana Scott had investigated the above system, proved its equi-interpretability with  ZFC, others did similar work with other standard theories, but I don't see an intuitive explication of the entities in those theories, in the sense of intuitive completeness mentioned above.

***Question:*** Had that matter been explored before?

One thing to be mentioned is that since the axiomatization is a fragment of ZFC, a theory about sets, then whatever that intuitive account about those entities is, it must be part of the intuitive account about sets, in other words the intuitive notion I that the above system would be considered as intuitively complete of, must be "weaker" than the intuitive notion of "set". It must not  conflict with the notion of set, and definitely need not be stronger than it.

Presenting models of this theory in which some form of extensionality hold like models of  ZFA and trying to figure out the intuitive notion related to them won't be helpful in figuring out what I is, since they would be clearly a stronger notion than I and the axiomatic system above would be clearly intuitively incomplete with respect to it, since that weak form of Extensionality must be added to the above list of axiom for latter to be intuitively complete of, this is unhelpful much as presenting a model of this theory that is a model of  ZFC is unhelpful. We need an intuitive notion that just fits these axioms.

My personal attempt is that I think that those entities might be "*collectivity states of affairs*", those need not be extensional, nor well founded, nor choice respective. The same set of objects can be collected by distinct collectivity states of affairs, the latter refers to a process of collectivity of the collection, for example two distinct persons might collect the same collection, but the states of affairs of collectivity of that collection are distinct, having different details, etc.. so for that axiomatic system the "is a member of" intuition given to symbol epsilon is to be replaced with "is collected by", we see that collectivity need not respect foundation, since self-collectivity is a possibility, it can be cyclical, it can go to infinity. Choice is the main axiom that gives the impression of being about collectivity rather than collection, since it carries the impression of an act, still imagining non-choice respective collectivity is justified. Collectivity seems to be a weaker concept than a set, since the later is a collectivity state of affairs, but fairly specific and rigid one, one that is completely determined by what is collected. Even the cumulative hierarchy of sets, seems to be about collectivity rather than the passive set concept. So all in all the notion of collectivity state of affairs seems to fit this axiomatic system that the latter is judge to be intuitively complete of!

***Question:*** had there been a research on a topic that is similar to what I'm suggesting here, I mean the collectivity state of affairs.

Comment: "Intuitive completeness" is very unclear.  What is an intuitive notion, what is a "very basic aspect," and what is it to "grasp" such a thing?

Comment: I think "intuition" is not easy to define rigorously, here it is related to analysis of informal meanings, for example it is intuitive to say that sets are extensional, one can instinctively know, or even feel that, or as I state 'grasp' it. Yes these are not rigorous terms, but one can figure out what it means though. For example the intuitive picture behind ZFA doesn't fit the above system, it is stronger than it, this can be almost 'sensed' intuitively. I think though one can indeed find the place of defining intuition in analysis of informally presented meanings.

Comment: I have the impression that most of the work done these days on *intensional* equality is done in the context of some flavor of type theory.

Comment: This is murky. One person's intuition isn't someone else's. And ZF being intuitively complete? ZF's conception of sets is completely contrary to anyone's intuitive notion of sets (unless one's intuition comes from studying ZF). First, unrestricted comprehension fails. So a set is NOT "a collection of things defined by a predicate." Secondly, the axiom of infinity leads to a lot of trouble. All kinds of strangeness come out of assuming infinite sets exist. If there's anything ZF isn't, it's intuitive. One has to be trained to believe that ZF captures an intuitive notion of what a set is.

Comment: I am going to object to the premise of the question. ZFC does not express *any* intuitive notion, as its history of technical tradeoffs shows, the intuitive notion of "set" is incoherent when extended to infinite sets (part-whole axiom is irreconcilable with bijection principle), and it is highly unlikely that compilations of technical axioms correspond to any "intuitive notions". Those are hazy clusters that technical notions replace, not "express", and replace differently for different purposes.

Comment: It seems to me you are chasing a ghost, although a study of this system may well be of interest. Instead of the pretend precision of your "intuitive notion" I suggest a different approach to making it more "intuitive". Namely, finding a ZFC (ZF) model for it, the way that accessible pointed graphs serve as a model for Aczel's anti-foundational set theory. Even some intensional theories have such models. In that form you'll probably get more expert advice on Math Overflow.

Comment: @user4894, I think ZF is intuitively complete of the notion of "set", but it says more than just that, (so it is stronger than the intuitive notion of set), the concept of a set is weak concept, a collection of objects, this intuitively calls for extensionality, and to some authors for foundation as well, as far as these two aspects ZF completely captures them, but the other axioms are not very basic properties of the intuitive notion of set, they are technical. My point was restricted in this sense, but the fragment that I've showed lacks even those basic properties.

Comment: @Conifold, yes I agree with much of what you and user4894 said, see my reply above to user 4894, I'm only interested in the very basic properties of a notion, the approach you've suggested can be done, but I won't think it would shed much 'intuition' on the nature of those entities, you'll be explaining the weak by the strong, like explaining water in terms of oceans. I would like to know the weaker part of the notion of 'set' that lacks extensionality?

Comment: @user4894, I still hold (though not insistent) that a set is an extension of a predicate, it is an object illustrating a predicate, it mirrors predication by membership, so  'set' is a discriminative function on predicates much as number is a discriminative function on cardinality of sets, with number it is bijection that ensures the discrimination, with set it is the prediation-membership paralleling that is doing the trick. I don't think there is something wrong with this. That it failed for the general case of predicates doesn't mean it is wrong, it just mean that the domain of the

Comment: @user4894  ...... function 'set' is to be limited. I think it needs generally to be limited to first order predicates, and that saves it from paradoxes.

Comment: @Conifold: It sounds like it is *mathematics* you find unintuitive, not ZF in particular.

Comment: Maybe [Kanamori's paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.9839&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on the historical transformation from 19th century intensional classes to extensional sets would help. But ZF is the progeny of this transformation, and if one wishes to explore intensional intuitions the more promising approach is to scrap it as a framework rather than reshuffle the axioms.

Comment: @MonroeEskew It is just *formal* mathematics, mathematics as practiced is plenty intuitive. While the idea that formalisms "capture" intuitive notions does try to express something real it is so multiply misguided (starting with the naivete of "intuitive notion" sitting there to be "captured", and proceeding to wishful thinking that formalisms are suitable, or even meant, for such "capturing") that it is easier to start over in other terms than to try fixing it.

Comment: The techniques of ordinary math can be translated fairly faithfully into ZFC without any strange contortions.  Unlimited comprehension is never really used when dealing with numbers and functions and spaces.  Furthermore, your remark about part/whole vs. bijection principle goes back to Galileo; Zermelo and Frankel's hands are clean on that.

Answer (score 1):

In Computer Science, the simplest interpretation of this would be a class of multi-sets, containing references to const multi-sets.  But they could also have other properties.  I think traditionally though a common reason to deny ordinary extensionality is to produce [something like ZFA](https://mathoverflow.net/a/301083/124813) in a one-sorted universe.  This can be done by limiting non-extensionality to collectivities without elements and equating those to atoms<sup>2</sup>.  So you might intuitively interpret this system as a class of references to multisets that can contain atoms.

Edit: It is possible this is too strong and specific, so you might want to check it over.  This is an attempt at the most simple and conventional intuition on how to interpret a system of exactly those five axioms.  The key point I believe in excluding extensionality is that it allows multiple versions of sets, which by itself seems to suggest multisets.  Other than that, excluding choice and foundation while weakening extension can produce atoms as in ZFA per references.  I'm not sure "is collected by" is distinguishing in the universe itself without additional definitions given collection and separation.  If you were to implement a subset of the class though it would be.

---

2: cf. section 4.1 Weak extensionality and ZFA.  Kanamori, A., Gabbay, D. and Woods, J. (2012). Sets and Extensions in the Twentieth Century, Volume 6 (Handbook of the history of logic). Amsterdam: Elsevier, pp.582-583.

Comment: I think this explanation is too specific, and strong. I like the word "collectivities" those seem to be weaker than "collections" as I mentioned in the main posting.

Comment: If you add references this would help your answer and give me something to check. For example, do you have a reference claiming "the common reason to deny ordinary extensionality is to produce something like ZFA in a one-sorted universe"?

Comment: @Frank changed to "a common reason" and added a reference

Comment: Yes this multi-set +atoms and other violations of foundation and choice can present models of this theory, but this is not the point. The point is at intuitive level what are those entities, I saw in multi-sets there is an interpretation of them in terms of sets, which is what I don't like, since intuitively speaking a multi-set is a weaker notion than a set, so it must cover wider range of entities more than just sets, to go interpret them in terms of a special sector of sets, is going in the opposite direction. as I said is like defining water in term of oceans.